# One liner to generate dynamically the step attribute for a number type input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input of type `number` :

```html
<input type="number">
```

There is no `step` attribute, but the user can start to enter a number like "21", "1.12", "0.00123", and on keydup, a script will determine the proper `step`. So for instance for 21 that would be 1, for 1.12 that would be 0.01, for 0.00123 that would be 0.00001, and so on.

I tried this:

```js
input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const value = input.value;
  if (value.split('.').length === 1) {
    input.step = 1
    return
  }
  
  let precision = value.split('.')[1].replace(/./g, '0')
  precision = `0.${precision.substring(0, precision.length - 1)}1`
  console.log(`precision: ${precision}`)

  input.step = precision
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
```

It seems to work, but how can I apply this process (in the event handler function) in a one liner?

Comment: Why do you think you need a one liner?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish by refactoring the code?

Comment: I don't really need one but this type of question brings a lot of nice knowledge about the language itself.

Comment: To be consistent, shouldn't the step be 1000 when I enter 9000?

Comment: In general I don't understand how this would not be deeply surprising and possibly infuriating to a user.

Comment: [Here is your one liner](https://jsbin.com/giwacifahe/1/edit?html,js,console,output). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Pointy What do you mean ? It's just for education purpose, I am not the type of guy to one liner my code in every part just to infuriate my colleagues.

Comment: @VLAZ I like this kind of humor, but you know this is not really what I was asking. by one liner I mean the definition of `step` from an input value.

Comment: @trincot not in this case.

Comment: Yes, I do. I also know that it's not a very practical problem to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  console.log(`precision: ${1 / Math.pow(10, input.value.split('.')[1]?.length ?? 0)}`)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
```

Comment: is `?` after `[1]` typescript typing ?

Comment: no, it is a standart JS feature, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 3):

A "one-liner" could be with a double call to `replace`:

```js
input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) =>
  input.step = input.value.replace(/[^.]/g, "0").replace(/\d$/, "1")
);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
```

Or with the `split` you used:

```js
input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) =>
  input.step = +input.value % 1 ? "0." + "1".padStart(input.value.split(".")[1].length, "0"): 1
);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a oneliner - but quite clean and readable:

```
const fractionalPartLength = input.value.split('.')[1] && input.value.split('.')[1].length || 0
const precision = 10**(0-fractionalPartLength)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize and reduce the complexity of your script by using only two replace:

```js
input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  input.step = input.value.replace(/\d/g, '0').replace(/\d$/, '1');
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
```